# Is it possible to create a good mix of MVC and Silverlight?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

We have big Silverlight project, we want to migrate it to MVC, however - since the project is huge, we will not get the funds needed to port it all at once, so we are considering the mix of MVC and Silverlight that - over time - would become pure MVC app.

Question is - Is it possible to load Silverlight once, and cache it even if it is not displayed on the current page, so there would be no noticeable delay every time user jumps to HTML base context and then back to Silverlight?

I don't know what other pitfalls there may be, the idea seems simple but we have to be sure this can be done without a big mess, before we start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just gone through something similar. The solution I applied was to host the Silverlight application in a separate iframe and hide/show the iframe depending on the navigation type.

This did present some issues because in some browsers (Chrome), if you actually *hide* the Silverlight object it disposes it.

I solved that by "moving" the iframe off-screen (top: -10000; bottom: 1000;) on "HTML navigation".

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... please tell me - did the "move iframe" trick worked on all major browsers, or where there problem on some? I must say doing exactly the same ugly hack crossed my mind, but I was afraid it will not work, or work only on some browsers.

Comment: Moving the iframe off-screen worked fine on IE and Chrome. I didn't really test it in Firefox or Safari.